# How to set application name and description for Android Market Place?

Tags: android

I need to publish my first application to android marketplace. The app will be supporting multiple languages, so I would like name and description to be set separately for all the languages supported.

Additionally I want the name of the app shown on device (launcher) to be different from name in the market place. I guess name for the app on the device which is currently being taken from following tag will not conflict with the name of app in the market place

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
```

So simply putting it, How can I set name and description of the app for market place in different language, and keep the name in marketplace different from name on device?

--**Edit**--

I can see following attributes for  tag in android manifest documentation

```
android:description
android:label
```

The documentation does not say anything on setting Values in marketplace, but does these values effect the description or label in Android Market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set name and description of the application from Google Developer Console after uploading your application on market.

There is on **Listing Details** section, you can provide name and description of your android application differ than the Name used in the Application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you upload your application to the Google Developer Console you are given the chance to set all the details ranging from the name and description to prices and screenshots.

Once you have uploaded the apk, and set these values you are then given the chance to publish the app.